# Forward declaration C

Tags: c, linux

I have 2 header files api.h and impl.h

`api.h` is visible to outside files and will be included in other ".c" files. So api.h includes `impl.h`

api.h defines 2 structures

```
typedef struct
    {
    uint32_t att;
    union
    {
        struct
        { 
            void* buffer;
            size_t length;
        } x;  
        struct
        {
            int a, b;
        } v;
    } content;
}dummy;
```

and impl.h has some other structures and function def which uses this structure. 
I tried forward declaration but it doesn't help me .

Please help .

Comment: But what is the problem?

Comment: How exactly are you doing the forward declaration. What does it mean `it doesn't help me`? We really need more information to help you.

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: shouldn't `impl.h` actualy include `api.h` and not the other way around?

Comment: Assuming `api.h` exposes the libs interface, and `impl.h` shall not be part of this, but stay private to the lib, then it is a bad idea to include `impl.h` in `api.h`. It should be the other way round.

Comment: I tried adding typedef struct dummy_ dummy in my impl.h but it doesnt work . I have another struct typedef struct
{
    uint32_t objectType;
} Info ; in api.h and typedef struct TEST
{
   /*
    * The object info
    */
   Info Info;

} TEST; in api.h  how shd i do the fwd declartation in api.h

Comment: I tried typedef struct info info in api.h . Compiler gives me error for my TEST struct stating sInfo has incomplete type

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your `dummy` is not a structure, but a `typedef` to an unnamed structure. Try naming the structure, you can then forward-declare it:

```
typedef struct sdummy dummy; // forward declaration

void foo(dummy *);

struct sdummy { ... }; // definition
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but they are standard structures I cant change it or rename it .

Answer (score 1):

Either reorder your code in `api.h` so the type declaration precedes the `#include "impl.h"` or give your (currently anonymous) structure itself a name like `dummy`, `dummy_`, `dummy_s` so you can add a forward declaration

```
typedef struct dummy_ dummy;
```

to `impl.h`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the details of your struct then you have to define it in some `.c` file, let's say `impl.c`, so that it has internal linkage to that compilation unit. To use it you have to expose create, destroy, getter and setter functions. So a basic setup would look like this:

`api.h` with forward declaration for your struct

```
// forward declaration
typedef struct dummy* dummy_t;

// create / destroy / setter / getter (omitted)
dummy_t alloc_dummy();
void free_dummy(dummy_t);
void set_number(dummy_t, int);
void set_string(dummy_t, char*);
void print_dummy(dummy_t);
```

Then comes `impl.c`

```
#include "api.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct dummy {
    int n;
    char* s;
};

dummy_t alloc_dummy()
{
    return malloc(sizeof(struct dummy));
}

void free_dummy(dummy_t dummy)
{
    if(dummy) {
        free(dummy->s);
        free(dummy);
    }
}

void set_number(dummy_t dummy, int n)
{
    if(dummy) {
        dummy->n = n;
    }
}

void set_string(dummy_t dummy, char* s)
{
    if(dummy && s) {
        dummy->s = strdup(s);
    }
}

void print_dummy(dummy_t dummy)
{
    if(dummy) {
        printf("%d, %s\n", dummy->n, dummy->s);
    }
}
```

And finally the usage in some other C files, here `main.c`

```
#include "api.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    // struct dummy d; // error! type is unknown
    // instead use the create function
    dummy_t d = alloc_dummy();
    // d->n = 1; // error! dereference of unknown type
    // instead use the setter function
    set_number(d, 1);
    set_string(d, "Hello, world!");
    print_dummy(d);
    free_dummy(d);
    return 0;
}
```

**Ouput**

```
1, Hello, world!
```